# Intellij IDEA: can I configure code style to put dot operator on previous line?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 14.1.4, formatting plain Java code.

IDEA does this:

```
  super.getFoo()
    .foo()
    .getBar()
    .bar();
```

I want it to do this:

```
super.getFoo().
  foo().
  getBar().
  bar();
```

Anyone know how to tell it to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a setting to do this. But there is a feature request to add this: [IDEA-123881 Code Formatting: method chain wrapping - Java configure position of dot operator](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123881)  I recommend you vote for it and watch it.